# JMS applications throws error on deploying in WAS 8.5 in the environment whereas it works fine in local WAS(same version v8.5)

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-8

I am getting the error when I deploy in the Test environment WAS server whereas it works fine in local WAS. Could someone please assist?

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: Bean class com.TestMDB could not be loaded
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3422)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:748)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:564)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:633)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: Bean class com.TestMDB could not be loaded
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.loadCustomerProvidedClasses(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:4151)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.finishBMDInitForReferenceContext(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:7807)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.finishBMDInitForReferenceContext(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:1678)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3415)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMCFRE006 invalid StackMap/StackMapTable attribute; class=com/TestMDB, method=onMessage(Ljavax/jms/Message;)V, pc=101
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:727)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.loadCustomerProvidedClasses(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:4088)
```

Comment: When you say "Test environment WAS", do you mean using RAD UTC or something else?  Are you using any bytecode weaving tools?

Comment: StackMap errors usually mean something that doesn't like java7+ bytecode is looking at java7+ bytecode. hard to tell without more information. Are both environments using the same JRE?

Comment: @BrettKail..We don't use any byte code weaving tools.

Comment: @ewhoch.. We use IBM JRE in the environment and oracle JRE in the local machine.If the issue is because of the difference in JRE then is it possible to find which is causing the bytecode mismatch? Is this the abstract error? What is the best solution?

Comment: You cannot be using Oracle JVM in local environment as traditional WebSphere doesn't support Oracle JVM, unless you are using WebSphere Liberty profile. Are you using same WAS version in local and test?

Comment: yes I use WAS 8.5 in local and not the Liberty profile.